# How to include a php file in a class function which it's gonna change its page type (CAPTCHA)

Tags: php, class

I have a CAPTCHA class which it has a function to generate the CAPTCHA. As you know when the CAPTCHA is generated, it should be returned like an image so the page should change its `Content-type` to `image` mime-type. The CAPTCHA class itself works great, but I wanted to include its class in another class and handle the CAPTCHA generating by myself with calling the relative function. I know there is something really wrong in my code but I can't figure it out, whenever I call the function from the alternative class which is the controller of CAPTCHA generator, PHP pops me an error which it says 'The generated image contains error and cannot be shown'. I know it's because of the header changing but I want to find a way to solve this.

Can someone tell me how to implement this?

My CAPTCHA class:

```
class CaptchaSecurityImages { 
public function MakeCaptcha($width='120', $height='40', $session='CaptchaCode', $characters='6') {
      $code = $this->generateCode($characters);
      /* font size will be 75% of the image height */
      $font_size = $height * 0.85;
      $image = @imagecreate($width, $height) or die('Cannot initialize new GD image stream');
      /* set the colours */
      $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);
      $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 20, 40, 100);
      $noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 100, 120, 180);
      /* generate random dots in background */
      for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/3; $i++ ) {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), 1, 1, $noise_color);
      }
      /* generate random lines in background */
      for( $i=0; $i<($width*$height)/150; $i++ ) {
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), mt_rand(0,$width), mt_rand(0,$height), $noise_color);
      }
      /* create textbox and add text */
      $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $this->font, $code) or die('Error in imagettfbbox function');
      $x = ($width - $textbox[4])/2;
      $y = ($height - $textbox[5])/2;
      imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $this->font , $code) or die('Error in imagettftext function');
      /* output captcha image to browser */
      header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
      imagejpeg($image);
      imagedestroy($image);
      $_SESSION[$session] = $code;
    }
}
```

My CAPTCHA controller:

```
class CaptchaController
  {
    /// Constructor
    public function __construct() { }

    /// Generate captcha
    public function Generate($width = '120', $height = '40', $session = 'CaptchaCode', $chars = '6')
    {
      include('captcha.php');
      $captcha = new CaptchaSecurityImages();
      $captcha->MakeCaptcha();
    }
  }
```

Comment: I know it's completely not answering your question, but... would it not be easier to just use reCaptaha (http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/?) They have a very nice PHP client.

Comment: I have to make something like this for my system so it's not the CAPTCHA generator itself problem. The problem is the way of implementing.

Comment: Recaptcha is the worst technology ever to come out of Google. I usually need 2-4 attempts to get their crappy image right. They should pay me for all the time I wasted on trying to read their images

Answer (score 1):

First you have to make shure, that there is NOTHING (not even a space) send, before calling the function, because afterwards you won't be able to send headers.

Second, just remove your "header(...)" stuff, and call the page itself, so it tells you some binary-image stuff. 
I got your error everytime, when in the image there is a PHP-Error / Notice / Whatever, wich is destroying your image. Just try to see the output plain and you can read what has happened!

I am a little bit confused about your method declarations: You expect parameters to your "Generate" function, but never use them? and you redefine these Parameters in the MakeCaptcha function. That can cause errors in later use of this Captcha-lib (or maybe now?)

With your error description i cannot help you any further than that, maybe you can post a link, where this captcha is used (with the error) so we can find your mistake for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know I should use `header` before any character in the page even UTF-8 with its mark. But the captcha itself works great there is nothing with it. If I remove `header` it would never return any image just a binary data. So how can I turn it to the right image format? About my code, I didn't pass the parameters because I wanted to just post it here, the real one is correct. At last, it is on my `localhost` can't upload it right now.

Comment: Is that error you get an error in your browser or an error from PHP? Have you tried cleaning the Cache? Trying another Browser? There may also be anywhere in your scripts a little space, you didn't find. 
A solution may be, to block putput witch 'ob_start()' and flush it with 'ob_end_flush()', and THEN generate the captcha (as long as you do not include any further scripts this could solve this issue)

Comment: The error is from PHP. You were right about `header`. It's in some kind of position that many characters can come before it. Anyway I gave up this way and directly included it into my image source path. Thanks for paying attention.